# How to best represent a network/graph using a tree

Tags: tree, graphs, data-tree

I have a data structure that is **network-like** or **graph-like**.

Most of the time a tree is sufficient, because it can fit into a tree model, but sometimes the branches can fuse together. If you want to represent this in a typical tree I can see no other way than to duplicate these nodes.

For example in the bottom diagram :

'Outlet Group 1' appears twice even though it is just one instance (Two branches are meeting up). There is a similar situation with the node called '30201-1'.

[image: Tree Demo]

Is there anything else that could be used to convey to the user that we are not dealing with a typical tree?

- I was thinking of highlighting all the duplicate nodes. When a user clicks on one of the nodes all instances highlight up :

[image]

- Alternatively I could list that the node has multiple parents in the right panel.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need to explain the relationship? What fails in the UX if just implement a continuously expanding tree.

Answer (score 4):

You may use a symbol for every subsequent instance (see image below). You may use the windows shortcut symbol or any other symbol that is meaningful to users.

[image]

Comment: so the first instance looks normal. All other instances look visually different with a shortcut link?

Comment: Yes. You may also add functionality on the shortcut icons, when clicked navigate to the first instance.